# GtkSharp: Do there exist some books?

Tags: gtk, gtk#

i'm trying to develop an application with Gtk# and MonoDevelop. 
I like Mono and i like Gtk#, but the problem is there's a lack of "official" book about it.

You could say "there is mono site with documentation", i know, but i would like to find a "comprehensive" book about Gtk#, like the classics Wrox or aPress book about .net, asp.net etc.

Does anyone know if exists what i'm looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write it :-))

Seriously, all you need to do is this:

> 1. Install GTK runtime
> 2. Install GTK#
> 3. Get the GTK# assemblies from the GAC and reference them in your project
> 4. Start glade and create a window with some buttons, textboxs, etc.
> 5. Save the glade file
> 6. Create a new console application and copy the text from mono gtk#
>      "getting started" program in there, or
>      google for a gtk# hello world program.

On point 6 you have to use intellisense for loading of the glade file, because the parameters changed (other sequence) since the tutorial was written.

That's all. You can still tell visual studio to open .glade files with Glade, that way you get a smooth experience.

From there on, you can google any minor issue if you have a problem. 
If that doesn't solve the problem, there still is the mono mailing list, or the stackoverflow forum.

If you need any deeper knowledge of GTK, you can buy a C/C++ book over GTK. But all the problems you will have is probably sizers and datagridview.

Comment: Note however that many (most?) GTK books cover C language only.  Be careful that you don't end up using procedural paradigms in your object-oriented language just because the book's examples did.